# Available min max values for SMB protocol

Tags: samba, smb, protocols

I am running Samba 3.6 in SLES 11.4.  I recently added in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` in the `[global]` section the following

- min protocol = SMB2
- max protocol = SMB2

this was done to allow communication with Windows 10 clients that are starting to come online, and also continue to work with existing win7 PCs.

**Does anyone know or how can i find out, the available protocols I can use?**

I thought, and tried, setting the min & max protocol to `SMB2.1` but my test client which is Windows7 immediately fails to connect.  I thought SMB2.1 was available in win7?  And how do I know `SMB2.1` is a valid choice in Samba 3.6?

Is `SMB3` a valid choice in Samba v3.6?

Comment: You should do more research before posting a question.

Comment: you should make such comments sooner than 5 years after a question was asked

Answer (score 14):

From the man page for the [configuration file for the Samba suite](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#CLIENTMAXPROTOCOL) in the "client max protocol" section:

> Possible values are :
>
> - CORE: Earliest version. No concept of user names.
> - COREPLUS: Slight improvements on CORE for efficiency.
> - LANMAN1: First modern version of the protocol. Long filename support.
> - LANMAN2: Updates to Lanman1 protocol.
> - NT1: Current up to date version of the protocol. Used by Windows NT.
>     Known as CIFS.
> - SMB2: Re-implementation of the SMB protocol. Used by Windows Vista and
>     later versions of Windows. SMB2 has sub protocols available.
> - SMB2_02: The earliest SMB2 version.
> - SMB2_10: Windows 7 SMB2 version.
> - SMB2_22: Early Windows 8 SMB2 version.
> - SMB2_24: Windows 8 beta SMB2 version.
>
> By default SMB2 selects the SMB2_10 variant.
>
> - SMB3: The same as SMB2. Used by Windows 8. SMB3 has sub protocols
>     available.
> - SMB3_00: Windows 8 SMB3 version. (mostly the same as SMB2_24)
> - SMB3_02: Windows 8.1 SMB3 version.
> - SMB3_10: early Windows 10 technical preview SMB3 version.
> - SMB3_11: Windows 10 technical preview SMB3 version (maybe final).
>
> By default SMB3 selects the SMB3_11 variant.
>
> Normally this option should not be set as the automatic negotiation
>   phase in the SMB protocol takes care of choosing the appropriate
>   protocol.
>
> The value default refers to SMB3_11.

Adding clarification from [A.B](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) in the comments:

> [wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba3/SMB2](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba3/SMB2) states "Samba 3.6 added basic support for SMB2.0", "Basic support for SMB 2.1 was added in Samba 4.0.0", "Basic support for SMB3 is included in Samba 4.0.0 and later."

Comment: thanks.  so trying to use `SMB2_10` is does not work.  I am having to use just `SMB2` otherwise I cannot connect from win7; and this is with Samba 3.6 in SLES 11.4.

Comment: what concerns me about Samba is that their help page makes no mention of what samba version that all applies to.  **I suspect much of it may only be valid in samba version 4 but not version 3.x ?**

Comment: I would expect (without having looked) that the man page provided with the corresponding version would list all & only the protocols that it supports.